# Twig conditional render if specific field in array of referenced entities contains text

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

In a template, I'm conditionally rendering a sidebar based on whether  the *content.field_body* custom field (a Paragraphs entity reference revisions field type) contains any items.

```
{% if content.field_body['#items'] %}
  <div class="jump-sidebar mb-5">
    <h3 class="text-sans">In this article:</h3>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      {% for item in content.field_body['#items'] %}
        {% if item.entity.field_subhead %}
          <li class="text-18">
            <a href="#{{ item.entity.field_subhead.value | clean_class | trim }}">{{ item.entity.field_subhead.value | raw }}</a>
          </li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

This worked fine until the requirements changed. Now I need to render this entire sidebar `<div>` if and only if one of the `item.entity.field_subhead` fields in the `['#items']` array contains a value.

`{{ dump(content.field_body['#items']|keys) }}` returns the following:

```
^ array:2 [▼
  0 => 0
  1 => 1
]
```

So the `['#items']` are a regular numerically-indexed array.

Is it possible, in a template file, to write a conditional that returns `true` if any key of a multi-value field contains a specific field?

This is further complicated by the fact that there may be different Paragraph types referenced here, and only one of these (the "Section" paragraphs type) will contain `entity.field_subhead`, but there might be any number of Sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd always do data checks on the entity object (in this case `node`), and not on the render array `content`. The second part is the magic `.entity` to get the linked referenced entity from the host's entity reference field:

```
{% set render_something = false %}
{% for field_item in node.field_entity_reference %}
  {% if not field_item.entity.field_to_check.isEmpty %}
    {% set render_something = true %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if render_something %}
  <div class="my_wrapper">
    ...content...
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Be warned though data behind `.entity` is usually not cache-safe (but it is cache-safe in this special case with Paragraphs, because their revisioning is directly tied to their host entity)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Hudri!

For future reference, the code that worked in my case looked like this:

```
{# Test every Section for non-empty Subhead #}
{% set render_sidebar = false %}
{% for field_item in node.field_body %}
  {% if field_item.entity.field_subhead %}
    {% if not field_item.entity.field_subhead.isEmpty %}
      {% set render_sidebar = true %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{# If any Section contains non-empty Subhead, render block #}
{% if render_sidebar %}
  <div class="jump-sidebar mb-5">
    {# a bunch of markup #}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```